# Manage process and form with powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, process

I am trying to develop in powershell, I know

```
Get-Process
```

I want two things, to set focus an application (windows), but when I try to get its PID: get-process
I can only see its father process, how can I join all form from a PID ?
I've found it

```
    [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::AppActivate(ID)
```

but it doesn't foreground the form i want ... how can i specify which form from the PID i want to foreground ?

(I am on windows 8.1) thanks

Comment: You can supply a window title as the argument if you want to set focus on a specific window: `[Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::AppActivate("MyForm")`

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, `AppActivate()` works in two ways.

If you pass an integer as an argument, the main window of the process with that process ID will come into focus.

If you want to activate a specific window, you can also pass in the Title text of that Window:

```
[Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::AppActivate
```

Do demonstrate, I've put together a simple Windows Forms application that launches two forms, the first of which I would like to activate after launching both:

[image: Forms voodo]

Comment: Can I list all form ? Count them ?